# D3: adding a line when clicking on a circle in scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatter plot. Now if I click on one of the points, how can I generate a line passing through that point?

I am stuck at two places:

1. With the following code, why is my line now showing?
      
   `<!DOCTYPE html>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <body>
   <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   var width = 500, height = 500;
   var randomX=[], randomY=[];
   for (var i=0; i<=50; i++) {
     randomX[i] = Math.random()*400;
     randomY[i] = Math.random()*400;}

   var data = randomX.concat(randomY);
   var x = d3.scale.linear()
             .domain([0, d3.max(randomX)])
             .range([0, width]);

   var y = d3.scale.linear()
             .domain([0, d3.max(randomY)])
             .range([height, 0]);

   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height)
       .append("g");

       svg.selectAll("scatter-dots")
          .data(randomY)
          .enter().append("svg:circle")
          .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d); } )
          .attr("cx", function(d,i) {return x(randomX[i]); } )
          .style("fill", "brown")
          .attr("r", 5)
          .on("click", function(d,i) {
               d3.select(this)
               .append("svg:line")
               .attr("x1", 300).attr("y1", 300)
               .attr("x2", 50).attr("y2", 50)
               .style("stroke", "steelblue")
               .style("stroke-width", 3);
          });
   </script>`
2. Where is the coordinates of my clicked point stored? I tried `this.cx` and `this.cy`, but none of them gave me the actual coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to append the `line` element to the top-level SVG or a `g` element, not a `circle` element, otherwise it won't be shown. So in your click handler, you would need to do this:

```
.on("click", function(d,i) {
      svg.append("svg:line")
        .attr("x1", 300).attr("y1", 300)
        .attr("x2", 50).attr("y2", 50)
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("stroke-width", 3);
   });
```

You can get the coordinates of the click either through [`d3.event`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_event) or the coordinates of the circle itself, i.e.

```
.on("click", function(d,i) {
  var x = x(randomX[i]),
      y = y(d);
});
```

or even

```
.on("click", function(d,i) {
  var x = d3.select(this).attr("cx"),
      y = d3.select(this).attr("cy");
});
```